# What is the purpose of the NCPD Hazmat Suit?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I found a Hazmat Suit that can be equipped in the special slot.

[image]

Does it serve any purpose? Because there are no description or stats presented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this suit does not serve a purpose other than character aesthetic. Special outfits are uncommon outfits that cover your typical clothes and (as far as I've seen) don't offer additional benefits, armor, or bonuses. While wearing special outfits, you retain the armor and benefits of the other clothing you have equipped, but the visual aspect is overridden by whatever special clothing you have on.

If you have high-quality but really garish clothing, you can hide it with a special outfit. Apart from that it doesn't do much in the game.

Comment: Some special clothing is specifically called for by a specific mission however. (Such as the suit during The Heist)

Answer (score 1):

There is one other apparent purpose for hazmat suits - they lock out clothing changes. Presumably this is to prevent accidental "equip while looting" issues while you are looting in combat.